# No puedo cambiar el color del botón de una segunda ventana en tkinter

Tags: python-3.x

Cuando pongo el código bg = "blue", en todos los botones de la función def openNewWindow1:, no me aparecen los botones que coloque en el código, ya intente poniendo boton.config(bg = "blue") y poniéndole en diferentes partes del código, pero no me funciona. Y cuando lo imprimo con bg = "blue", me sale que se desconoce el código -bg. aquí dejo el código:

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.ttk import *
import os, webbrowser, shutil

principal = Tk()
principal.title("Escuela")
principal.geometry("200x200") 

def openNewWindow():
    newWindow = Toplevel(principal)
    newWindow.title("Preparación de escaneo")
    newWindow.geometry("250x200")
    Label(newWindow, text ="¿Cual es el nombre de la carpeta?").pack()
    boton = Button(newWindow, text = "Crear carpeta", command = lambda: os.makedirs(entry.get(), webbrowser.open("https://www.google.com")))
    boton1 = Button(newWindow, text = "Mover carpeta", command = lambda: shutil.move(entry.get(), "escaneo"))
    boton1.pack(pady = 10)
    boton1.place(x=70, y=60)
    boton.pack(pady = 10)
    boton.place(x=140, y=27)
    entry = Entry(newWindow)
    entry.pack()
    entry.place(x=10, y=30)
    
def openNewWindow1():
    newWindow1 = Toplevel(principal)
    newWindow1.title("Imprimir")
    newWindow1.geometry("350x200")
    Label(newWindow1, text ="¿Que quieres imprimir hoy?").pack()
    boton = Button(newWindow1, text = "Az express", bg = "blue", command = lambda: os.startfile("Az Express.docx", "print"))
    boton1 = Button(newWindow1, text = "Escuela", bg = "blue", command = lambda: os.startfile("Escuela.docx", "print"))
    boton2 = Button(newWindow1, text = "Escuela", bg = "blue", command = lambda: os.startfile("Escuela.pdf", "print"))
    boton3 = Button(newWindow1, text = "Colegio", bg = "blue", command = lambda: os.startfile("Colegio.pdf", "print"))
    boton4 = Button(newWindow1, text = "CSB Express", bg = "blue", command = lambda: os.startfile("CSB Express.pdf", "print"))
    boton5 = Button(newWindow1, text = "Escuela", bg = "blue", command = lambda: os.startfile("Escuela.pdf", "print"))
    boton6 = Button(newWindow1, text = "Colegio", bg = "blue", command = lambda: os.startfile("Colegio.pdf", "print"))
    boton.pack(pady = 10)
    boton.place(x=50, y=30)
    boton1.pack(pady = 10)
    boton1.place(x=155, y=30)
    boton2.pack(pady = 10)
    boton2.place(x=20, y=60)
    boton3.pack(pady = 10)
    boton3.place(x=150, y=60)
    boton4.pack(pady = 10)
    boton4.place(x=50, y=90)
    boton5.pack(pady = 10)
    boton5.place(x=155, y=90)
    boton6.pack(pady = 10)
    boton6.place(x=70, y=120)

label = Label(principal, text ="¿Que quieres hacer hoy")
label.pack(pady = 10)

botones = Button(principal, text ="Para Escaneo", command = openNewWindow)
botones.pack(pady = 10)


botones1 = Button(principal, text ="Imprimir", command = openNewWindow1)
botones1.pack(pady = 10)

mainloop()
```

Aquí dejo como me imprime el código a recopilaro:
[image: Aquí dejo como me imprime]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

El problema es que importas todo de `tkinter` y de `tkinter.tkk`

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.ttk import *
```

En ambos componentes existe el `widget` "Button" y tienen diferentes argumentos, como `tkk` está importado después de `tkinter` al momento de utilizar `Button` estás utilizando el botón de `tkk` y este no tiene el argumento `bg`

En general no es muy recomendable importar todo de esa forma, lo que podrías hacer es darles un alias si en realidad necesitas todos los elementos de un módulo, por lo general se utilizan nombres significativos o representantes pero podría ser cualquier cosa

```
import tkinter.ttk as modTtk
```

O importar módulos específicos de una librería

```
from tkinter import ttk
```

Pero en lo que has hecho hasta el momento no has utilizado `tkk` por lo que podrías comentarlo y ya funcionaría.

Ejemplo:

```
from tkinter import *
#from tkinter import ttk
import os, webbrowser, shutil

principal = Tk()
principal.title("Escuela")
principal.geometry("200x200") 

def openNewWindow():
    newWindow = Toplevel(principal)
    newWindow.title("Preparación de escaneo")
    newWindow.geometry("250x200")
    Label(newWindow, text ="¿Cual es el nombre de la carpeta?").pack()
    boton = Button(newWindow, text = "Crear carpeta", command = lambda: os.makedirs(entry.get(), webbrowser.open("https://www.google.com")))
    boton1 = Button(newWindow, text = "Mover carpeta", command = lambda: shutil.move(entry.get(), "escaneo"))
    boton1.pack(pady = 10)
    boton1.place(x=70, y=60)
    boton.pack(pady = 10)
    boton.place(x=140, y=27)
    entry = Entry(newWindow)
    entry.pack()
    entry.place(x=10, y=30)
    
def openNewWindow1():
    newWindow1 = Toplevel(principal)
    newWindow1.title("Imprimir")
    newWindow1.geometry("350x200")
    Label(newWindow1, text ="¿Que quieres imprimir hoy?").pack()
    boton = Button(newWindow1, text = "Az express", bg = "blue", command = lambda: os.startfile("Az Express.docx", "print"))
    boton1 = Button(newWindow1, text = "Escuela", bg = "blue", command = lambda: os.startfile("Escuela.docx", "print"))
    boton2 = Button(newWindow1, text = "Escuela", bg = "blue", command = lambda: os.startfile("Escuela.pdf", "print"))
    boton3 = Button(newWindow1, text = "Colegio", bg = "blue", command = lambda: os.startfile("Colegio.pdf", "print"))
    boton4 = Button(newWindow1, text = "CSB Express", bg = "blue", command = lambda: os.startfile("CSB Express.pdf", "print"))
    boton5 = Button(newWindow1, text = "Escuela", bg = "blue", command = lambda: os.startfile("Escuela.pdf", "print"))
    boton6 = Button(newWindow1, text = "Colegio", bg = "blue", command = lambda: os.startfile("Colegio.pdf", "print"))
    boton.pack(pady = 10)
    boton.place(x=50, y=30)
    boton1.pack(pady = 10)
    boton1.place(x=155, y=30)
    boton2.pack(pady = 10)
    boton2.place(x=20, y=60)
    boton3.pack(pady = 10)
    boton3.place(x=150, y=60)
    boton4.pack(pady = 10)
    boton4.place(x=50, y=90)
    boton5.pack(pady = 10)
    boton5.place(x=155, y=90)
    boton6.pack(pady = 10)
    boton6.place(x=70, y=120)

label = Label(principal, text ="¿Que quieres hacer hoy")
label.pack(pady = 10)

botones = Button(principal, text ="Para Escaneo", command = openNewWindow)
botones.pack(pady = 10)


botones1 = Button(principal, text ="Imprimir", command = openNewWindow1)
botones1.pack(pady = 10)

mainloop()
```

Esto devuelve:

[image: Ventanas tkinter]